# Confused on Projective Bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, k-theory

I am working through Atiyah ([https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/atiyahk.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/atiyahk.pdf)) and am confused on the projective bundle (pg. 44-45). Atiyah states that for a vector bundle $E$ over $X$, let $E_0 = E-X$ and then $P(E)$ or the projective bundle is just the quotient space of $E_0$ divided by the action of the complex numbers. My confusion is twofold: how can one subtract $X$ from $E$, or what does Atiyah mean by that? Also, I am a bit confused on what the "action of the complex numbers" means. I have tried looking it up and haven't found anything helpful. For context, I am working through this book as part of a program at my university without having taken algebra or topology properly yet, so I am just trying to get as good of a grasp as possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think rather than thinking $E-X$ as subtraction, you should consider it as set theoretical complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $E - X$ is another notation for $E\setminus X$. As Atiyah mentions, here we are viewing $X$ inside of $E$ via the zero section.

As $E \to X$ is a complex vector bundle, the fibers are complex vector spaces, so $\mathbb{C}$ acts on $E$ via scalar multiplication. Removing the zero section, we see that $\mathbb{C}^*$ acts on $E - X$ via scalar multiplication. Then $\mathbb{P}(E) = (E-X)/\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just have two quick questions: viewing $X$ inside of $E$ as the zero section means $X$ is just getting mapped to the zero vector in $E$, correct? That's what's being removed? And what do you mean by $\mathbb{C}^*$ acts on $E-X$ via scalar multiplication? I understand with $\mathbb{C}$ but what changes with $\mathbb{C}^*$? Thank you!

Comment: You say "the zero vector in $E$", but $E$ is not a vector space. Instead, for each $x \in X$, the fiber $E_x$ is a vector space and hence there is a zero vector $0_x \in E_x$. The zero section $\sigma : X \to E$ is given by $\sigma(x) = 0_x$. That is, the zero vector is being removed from each fiber. As for your last question, $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't act on $E - X$ as acting by zero lands in $X$ (not $E - X$), however, if $e \in E - X$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C} -\{0\}$, then $z\cdot e \in E - X$, so we still have an action by $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now!